# index for dimensional list (nested list)

Tags: python, list, numpy, indexing

Assuming I have a list below, how can I find all the indexes of an identified object in the list

WHAT I AM EXPECTING (ALL indexes of 'pen'):

```
OUTPUT: (0,0),(3,4),(4,4),(4,2),(3,4)
```

```
a_list = [['pen', 'pencil', 'eraser'], 
          ['ruler', 'paper', 'pen'], 
          ['pen', 'pen', 'bag'], 
          ['pencil', 'pen', 'paper']]


def finding(listoflist, stationary):
    for i in listoflist:
        if stationary in i:
            return (i.index(stationary)),(listoflist.index(i))

finding(a_list, 'pen')

OUTPUT: (0, 0)
```

Comment: You need to collect all the values, not return at the first one

Comment: Don't see why this post has ```numpy``` tag?!

Answer (score 2):

Since it was tagged numpy, here is the numpy approach:

```
import numpy as np

stationary = np.array([
    ['pen', 'pencil', 'eraser'], 
    ['ruler', 'paper', 'pen'], 
    ['pen', 'pen', 'bag'], 
    ['pencil', 'pen', 'paper']
])

out = list(zip(*np.where(stationary == "pen")))
```

```
[(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fun(a_list,search_item):
    res=[]
    for i1,nest in enumerate(a_list):
        for i2,item in enumerate(a_list[i1]):
            if item==search_item:
                res.append((i1,i2))
    return res
```

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate answer. Please don't post those; if you have 600 rep, you should know this by now.

Comment: Beg pardon, but by the time i posted mine there were no other answers.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed it was a dupe because it was in LQA; besides, all the answers were posted "6 hours ago", so I can't tell which one came first.